# Django: Update all records in a table when I insert a new record

Tags: python, django, django-models

hello friends i need help!

It turns out that I have a `model` which has several properties, I use it to obtain the consumption of the readings of a meter. The consumption is obtained through some property and then I obtain the `total consumption` in another property.

```
class ConsumoElect(models.Model):
    pgd = models.ForeignKey(TipoPGD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='consumoelect')
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    fecha_AM = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    lec_madrugada = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_dia = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_pico = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reactivo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dato = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.pgd)

    def get_cm(self):
        c_m = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_madrugada', 'fecha'))       
        if not c_m:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_m[0]['lec_madrugada']:
                return 0
            else: 
                return ((c_m[0]['lec_madrugada'] - self.lec_madrugada))    
    consumo_m= property(get_cm)

    def get_cd(self):
        c_d = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_dia')[0:1])   
        if not c_d:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_d[0]['lec_dia']:
                return 0
            else:
                return ((c_d[0]['lec_dia'] - self.lec_dia))    
    consumo_d= property(get_cd)

    def get_cp(self):
        c_p = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_pico')[0:1])    
        if not c_p:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_p[0]['lec_pico']:
                return 0
            else:
                return ((c_p[0]['lec_pico'] - self.lec_pico))    
    consumo_p= property(get_cp)
   
    def get_total(self): 
        return (self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p)
    consumo_total= property(get_total) 
           
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fe=date.strftime(self.fecha, "%Y-%m")
        self.fecha_AM = fe          
        self.total = self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p   
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=['pgd', 'fecha']
        verbose_name = 'Consumo Electrico'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Consumo Electrico'
        ordering = ['pgd', 'fecha']
        db_table = 'consumoelect'
```

In the `views` I need to work with the `total consumption`, but the `ORM` does not admit working with the properties, so in the `save` I save the `total` value so that it is registered in the `DB` and if it is saved. The problem is that every time I insert a new record, the properties update the consumption, but the `total consumptio`n in the DB is not updated, only when I update record by record is the real value displayed.

I need that when I insert a new record, the other records in that `table` are updated, so that I can work with the real data of the `total consumption`

Comment: Question is: Do you really need `total consumption` as a field in your database? Why don't you write another property that computes the total on the fly? To create automatically updating db entries normally you would set up another program to run on your database over and over. To achieve this with django is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, I need to save the total consumption in a field since later I need to use it to carry out other calculations. What would the other program be?

Comment: You can still "carry out other calculations" with the property. I suggest going that route. Another program would be a short script that gets executed every few seconds and updates all fields. If you want to enforce it with django you could use a signal. In your case you want to run the update of `total consumption` after every save of the model; so use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save). But I guess bulk save and update don't work well with signals. One should try to not use signals if possible.

Comment: Hello friend, could you give an example of what you are proposing?

Comment: What other calculations do you have to carry out?

Comment: Later I will create a specific question for the calculation that I need to perform with the properties, as soon as I have it ready I will notify you

Comment: @Tarquinius here is the new question for the calculation I need, I hope it helps me, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222072/get-total-sum-using-property-in-django